# Linq equivalent of Except

Tags: c#, linq

```
var keys = m_ASPxGridView.GetCurrentPageRowValues("ID", "SID");
var selectedkeyValues = m_ASPxGridView.GetSelectedFieldValues("ID", "SID");

var unselected=keys- selected values

var unselected=keys.Except(selectedkeyValues)// does not work
```

Is it possible to write a linq query to get all the values from keys not [present in selectedkeyValues ?

Comment: Since both of those methods return `List<Object>`, `.Except()` should work as written, assuming the `Object`s returned are the same.  What "does not work" about it?

Comment: this most likely doesn't work because you are selecting two different values, ID and SID - since the return type is `List<object>` they cannot be differentiated between anymore, hence `Except()` will return garbage (and so will `Contains()`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything that [BrokenGlass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410339/linq-equivalent-of-except/5410520#5410520) and [pst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410339/linq-equivalent-of-except/5410437#5410437) have said is correct, but it seems there's still some confusion, stemming from the fact that these DevExpress methods return a `List<object>`, where `object` is:

> An object which is an array of field values (if several field names are passed via the fieldNames parameter) or a direct field value (if a single field name is passed via the fieldNames parameter). ([Source Link](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_GetRowValuestopic))

So, since you're passing multiple field names, code like this should work:

```
// Get the current values
var currentRowValues = m_ASPxGridView.GetCurrentPageRowValues("ID", "SID")
    // Cast each object to an array of objects
    .Cast<object[]>()
    // Project the two members of the array into an anonymous type
    .Select(x => new { ID = x[0].ToString(), SID = x[1].ToString() });
var selectedRowValues = m_ASPxGridView.GetSelectedFieldValues("ID", "SID")
    // Cast each object to an array of objects
    .Cast<object[]>()
    // Project the two members of the array into an anonymous type
    .Select(x => new { ID = x[0].ToString(), SID = x[1].ToString() });

// Compare the two collections to get the unselected row values
var unselected = currentRowValues.Except(selectedRowValues);
```

As we've been discussing, .NET won't know how to compare the two collections if they're of type `object`. However, it should work if they've been projected (using `Select`) to the same anonymous type -- I think by default it will use value-type equality.

**Edit:** According to Jon Skeet from **[C# in Depth](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182471)**:

> Within any given assembly, the compiler treats two anonymous object initializers as the same type if there are the same number of properties, with the same names and types, and they appear in the same order.
>
> ...
>
> Equality between two instances of the same anonymous type is determined in the natural manner, comparing each property value in turn using the property type's `Equals` method.

So, if I'm reading it right, the above code should do exactly what you're asking. Please let me know if I'm not ;-)

Comment: +1 Good catch on the "An object which is an array of field values" - that's the trick.

Comment: @BrokenGlass - Thanks! Yeah, I was really confused about those methods until I found that quote. Let me add some links in there ...

Comment: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

Comment: @Talk2me: Whoops, I forgot that we need to cast the `object` to an array of field values, so `object[]`.
Please let me know if it works now.

Comment: What a terrible, terrible API.

Comment: @Talk2me - Sure! Please mark as accepted answer if it was the answer that answered your question ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This works as described in [Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx). Make sure your objects are correctly handling `Equals` and `GetHashCode`. Here is a verification in LINQPad (2x -> C#3/.NET35):

```
var keys = new [] {"A", "B", "C"};
var selectedkeyValues = new [] {"A", "B"};
// var unselected=keys - selected values
var unselected=keys.Except(selectedkeyValues);
unselected.Dump(); // LINQPad support method -- remove in other contexts
```

Result: `["C"]`

Also, I am pretty sure ordering is *not* guaranteed in the above. Consider updating the original post with *what* "does not work" means.

Happy coding.

---

As Pandincus pointed out, a custom compare can be specified in the overload: [Enumerable.Except<<TSource> Method (IEnumerable<<TSource>, IEnumerable<<TSource>, IEqualityComparer<TSource>)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390.aspx).

Comment: +1 correct, since the method returns List<object>, there is most likely no way for it to determine how to check equality.
In addition, if the OP didn't want to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, a new `EqualityComparer` could be created. I'm fairly certain Except takes an `EqualityComparer` as one of its parameters.

Comment: Keys.Except(selectedkeyValues ) gives me {"A","B","C"}

Comment: I would define var in my case as List<Object> and my Object contains(int,int)

Comment: @Talk2me I am confused. Can you update the post with a test-case (using real locally-created objects) that can be run stand-alone that exhibits the same behavior of "does not work"? (e.g. not the results from `GetCurrentPageRowValues`)

Answer (score 2):

try  `keys.Where(x => !selectedkeyValues.Contains(x));`

Comment: This should return exactly the same thing as `keys.Except(selectedkeyValues)`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you want to compare a compound key (ID, SID) and these methods return *multiple properties* as a single `List<object>` so you don't have a handle on each different property separately. You should be able to project to an anonymous type depending on how they are stored (see [documentation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_GetSelectedFieldValuestopic)).

Assuming `ID` and `SID` are returned in alternate positions in the list (ID, SID, ID, SID, etc.) you could create a typed list of key (if ID is of type `int` convert appropriately):

```
List<object> keys = m_ASPxGridView.GetCurrentPageRowValues("ID", "SID");

var TypedKeys = keys.Zip(keys.Skip(1),
                        (a, b) => new { Id = a.ToString(), SID = b.ToString() })
                    .Where((x, i) => i % 2 == 0)
                    .ToList();
```

Now do the same with `selectedkeyValues` and the `Except()` should work.

Comment: No definition of Zip exists for generic list<Object>

Comment: add `using System.Linq;` to the top of your file

Comment: @Talk2Me: `Zip()` was introduced in .NET 4, that means unfortunately you are targeting an older .NET version - can you upgrade? If not, ignore the actual implementation, but the problem description still applies